# Show flyout near system back button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm porting a Windows 8.1 app to UWP.  On a particular screen, the user must fix all input errors before going back.  In the Windows 8.1 app, tapping the back button when errors are present shows a `Flyout` at the back button (instead of going back) that contains a warning.  But the UWP app uses the system-provided back button.  This may be the shell-drawn one or the tablet-mode one as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigation-history-and-backwards-navigation).

Is there a `FrameworkElement` I can get ahold of to pass to `FlyoutBase.ShowAt`?  Otherwise, how can I display the warning `Flyout` as near as possible to the system back button?  Its location will differ depending on tablet vs. desktop mode.

Comment: Can you not attach Flyout to the outermost Grid?

Comment: @Archana I could but what part of the grid?  I need to know where the system back button is.

Comment: You can specify Placement=bottom for that flyout? Can you post your flyout code?

Comment: @Archana That'd only work if the back button is on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determinate where is the system back button roughly (upper left corner or bottom left corner) from the `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIViewSettings.UserInteractionMode` property which is basically determines the app is running in desktop or tablet mode.

Also you can create two dummy 0px `Border` to place the flyouts.

**Example:**

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Border x:Name="DesktopBorder" Height="0" Width="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Button Content="test" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
    <Border x:Name="TabletBorder" Height="0" Width="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var flyout = new Flyout()
    {
        Content = new Rectangle() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Height = 100, Width = 100 }
    };

    if (UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode == UserInteractionMode.Mouse)
    {
        flyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Bottom;
        flyout.ShowAt(DesktopBorder);
    }

    if (UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode == UserInteractionMode.Touch)
    {
        flyout.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Top;
        flyout.ShowAt(TabletBorder);
    }
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image: desktop mode]

[image: tablet mode]